# How do you call class method from initialize method?

Tags: ruby, class, matrix, object-initializers

I'm trying to call a method in a class during its initialize method. Is this not allowed? I originally had the method outside of the class to try and use it as a global method. The current method is trying to return the created matrix and then the initialize method saves the returned matrix into an instance variable.

```
class Member
  def setMatrix(a, i, l)
    puts "here"
    m = Matrix.zero(6)
    m[0,0] = a*l**2/i
    m[0,3] = -a*l**2/i
    m[1,1] = 12
    m[1,2] = 6*l
    m[1,4] = -12
    m[1,5] = 6*l
    m[2,1] = 6*l
    m[2,2] = 4*l**2
    m[2,4] = -6*l
    m[2,5] = 2*l**2
    m[3,0] = -a*l**2/i
    m[3,3] = a*l**2/i
    m[4,1] = -12
    m[4,2] = -6*l
    m[4,4] = 12
    m[4,5] = -6*l
    m[5,1] = 6*l
    m[5,2] = 2*l**2
    m[5,4] = -6*l
    m[5,5] = 4*l**2
    return m
    #@k = m
   end

   def initialize(a, i, l)
     @area = a
     @i = i
     @length = l
     @k = setMatrix(a, i, l)
    end
end
```

Doing this returns this error

```
`'setMatrix': private method '[]=' called for #<Matrix:0x00000001186e00> (NoMethodError)
from truss_solver.rb:71:in 'initialize'
from truss_solver.rb:86:in 'new'
from truss_solver.rb:86:in 'block in <main>'
from truss_solver.rb:85:in 'each'
from truss_solver.rb:85:in '<main>'`
```

I would like it to make an instance variable of a matrix when the class is instantiated. I've also tried to have the setMatrix method save the matrix to @k directly instead of returning the matrix and that gave a similar error. How else can I do to achieve what I want?

Comment: "You said "doing this" returns this error..." Presumably, "this" includes the creation of an instance of `Member` (e.g., `Member.new(1,2,3)`), which is not shown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing to prevent you from calling methods within `initialize`, there's no special behaviour in there, but what you're calling here is a *private* method in another class.

I don't know why it's set `private`, and some people have observed [that seems to be a problem](http://www.fmendez.com/blog/2013/04/09/working-with-the-ruby-matrix-class/), so you can always just brute-force it:

```
matrix.send(:[]=, 1, 2, 3)
```

That seems messy, and patching it as recommended in that post might help simplify things:

```
class Matrix
  def []=(row, column, value)
    @rows[row][column] = value
  end
end
```

You could also subclass `Matrix` to `MutableMatrix` and include that method.

As a note, Ruby's naming conventions for methods is `underscore_style` and including an explicit `return` at the end isn't necessary, it's implied. `m` alone would do the job.

Comment: In addition, you should `raise ArgumentError if row >= row_count || column >= column_count` to ensure that `row` and `column` are within the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Let's get more information:

```
require 'matrix'
Matrix.instance_methods.include?(:[]=)
  #=> false
Matrix.private_instance_methods.include?(:[]=)
  #=> true
```

The latter was a surprise to me. Considering that `Matrix` objects are immutable, there should be no `:[]=` method. (It's akin to `2=4`, which of course raises an exception.) Perhaps it's used by Ruby for implementing `Matrix` methods. Can a reader explain why this undocumented private method exists?

If you wish to use that private instance method you can do as @tadman suggests.

My advice is to use [Matrix#build](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-c-build). (I've renamed `setMatrix` to `set_matrix` to conform with Ruby's convention for naming methods and variables.)

```
class Member
  def set_matrix(a, i, l)
    Matrix.build(6) do |r,c|
      case [r,c].sort
      when [0,0], [3,3] then a*l**2/i
      when [0,3]        then -a*l**2/i
      when [1,1], [4,4] then 12
      when [1,4]        then -12
      when [1,2], [1,5] then 6*l
      when [2,4], [4,5] then -6*l
      when [2,2], [5,5] then 4*l**2
      when [2,5]        then 2*l**2
      else              0
      end
    end
  end

  def initialize(a, i, l)
    @area = a
    @i = i
    @length = l
    @k = set_matrix(a, i, l)
  end
end
```

```
m = Member.new(1,2,3).instance_variable_get(:@k)
  #=> Matrix[[ 4,   0,   0, -5,   0,   0], 
  #          [ 0,  12,  18,  0, -12,  18],
  #          [ 0,  18,  36,  0, -18,  18],
  #          [-5,   0,   0,  4,   0,   0],
  #          [ 0, -12, -18,  0,  12, -18],
  #          [ 0,  18,  18,  0, -18,  36]]
```

Comment: Surprising indeed. Neither `[]=`, not its aliases `set_element` and `set_component` are used within the class.

Comment: The matrix is symmetric, so you could remove some redundant r,c/c,r-pairs from your `when`s by using `case [r,c].sort`. I'd also use the more compact `when ... then` form in this case.

Comment: @Stefan, I hadn't noticed it was symmetric. I incorporated your (clever) suggestion. Thanks. Can you explain "Unbound" in `Matrix.instance_method(:[]=) #=> #<UnboundMethod: Matrix#[]=>`, considering that it is not necessary to bind the method to the matrix object?

Comment: It's "Unbound" just because you don't have an instance. `String.instance_method(:upcase)` returns an `UnboundMethod`, whereas `'foo'.method(:upcase)` returns a (bound) `Method`.